# Get Gitlab's Continuous Integration to compile a Python extension written in C

Tags: python, gitlab, setuptools, gitlab-ci, python-unittest

## Context

I have a Python project for which I wrap some C/C++ code (using the excellent [PyBind](https://github.com/pybind) library). I have a set of C and Python unit tests and I've configured Gitlab's CI to run them at each push.
The C tests use a minimalist unit test framework called [minunit](https://github.com/siu/minunit) and I use Python's unittest suite.

Before running the C tests, all the C code is compiled and then tested. I'd like to also compile the C/C++ wrapper for Python before running the Python tests, but have a hard time to do it.

## Question in a few words

Is there a standard/good way to get `Gitlab-CI` to build a Python extension using `setuptools` before running unit-tests?

## Question with more words / Description of what I tried

To compile the C/C++ wrapper locally, I use `setuptools` with a `setup.py` file including a `build_ext` command. 
I locally compile everything with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` (the last arg `--inplace` will just copy the compiled file to the current directory).
As far as I know, this is quite standard.

What I tried to do on Gitlab is to have a Python script (code below) that will run a few commands using `os.system` command (which appears to be bad practice...).
The first command is to run a script building and running all C tests. This works but I'm happy to take recommendations (should I configure Gitlab CI to run C tests separately?).

Now, the problem comes when I try to build the C/C++ wrapper, with `os.system("cd python/ \npython setup.py build_ext --inplace")`. This generates the error

```
File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, Extension
    ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

So I tried to modify my gitlab's CI configuration file to install python-dev. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like

```
test:
  script:
  - apt-get install -y python-dev
  - python run_tests.py
```

But, not being sudo on the gitlab's server, I get the following error `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)`.
Anyone knows a way around that, or a better way to tackle this problem?

Any help would be more than welcome!

### run_tests.py file

```
    import unittest
    import os
    from shutil import copyfile
    import glob


    class AllTests(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_all(self):
            # this automatically loads all tests in current dir
            testsuite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests/Python_tests')
            # run tests
            result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(testsuite)
            # send/print results
            self.assertEqual(result.failures, [], 'Failure')


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        # run C tests
        print(' ------------------------------------------------------ C TESTS')
        os.system("cd tests/C_tests/ \nbash run_all.sh")

        # now python tests
        print(' ------------------------------------------------- PYTHON TESTS')
        # first build and copy shared library compiled from C++ in the python test directory
        # build lib 
        os.system("cd python/ \npython setup.py build_ext --inplace")
        # copy lib it to right place
        dest_dir = 'tests/Python_tests/'
        for file in glob.glob(r'python/*.so'):
            print('Copying file to test dir : ', file)
            copyfile(file, dest_dir+file.replace('python/', ''))
        # run Python tests
        unittest.main(verbosity=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be moving the entire test running logic into the setup script.

#### using `test` command

First of all, `setuptools` ships a `test` command, so you can run the tests via `python setup.py test`. Even better, the `test` calls `build_ext` command under the hood and places the built extensions so that they accessible in the tests, so no need for you to invoke `python setup.py build_ext` explicitly:

```
$ python setup.py test
running test
running egg_info
creating so.egg-info
writing so.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to so.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to so.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'so.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'so.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'so.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building 'wrap_fib' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fPIC -I/data/gentoo64/usr/include/python3.6m -c wrap_fib.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/wrap_fib.o
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fPIC -I/data/gentoo64/usr/include/python3.6m -c cfib.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/cfib.o
creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -L. build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/wrap_fib.o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.6/cfib.o -L/data/gentoo64/usr/lib64 -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/wrap_fib.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
copying build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.6/wrap_fib.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so ->
test_fib_0 (test_fib.FibonacciTests) ... ok
test_fib_1 (test_fib.FibonacciTests) ... ok
test_fib_10 (test_fib.FibonacciTests) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

(I used the code from the [Cython Book examples repository](https://github.com/cythonbook/examples/tree/master/01-essentials/02-wrapping-c-code-with-cython) to play with, but the output should be pretty similar to what PyBind produces).

#### using the extra keywords

Another feature that may come handy are the extra keywords `setuptools` adds: `test_suite`, `tests_require`, `test_loader` ([docs](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords)). Here's an example of embedding a custom test suite as you do in `run_tests.py`:

```
# setup.py

import unittest
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import setup, Extension

exts = cythonize([Extension("wrap_fib", sources=["cfib.c", "wrap_fib.pyx"])])


def pysuite():
    return unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests/python_tests')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        name='so',
        version='0.1',
        ext_modules=exts,
        test_suite='setup.pysuite'
    )
```

#### extending the `test` command

The last requirement is running C tests. We can embed them by overriding the `test` command and invoking some custom code from there. The advantage of that is that `distutils` offers a command API with many useful functions, like copying files or executing external commands:

```
# setup.py

import os
import unittest
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.test import test as test_orig


exts = cythonize([Extension("wrap_fib", sources=["cfib.c", "wrap_fib.pyx"])])


class test(test_orig):

    def run(self):
        # run python tests
        super().run()
        # run c tests
        self.announce('Running C tests ...')
        pwd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir('tests/C_tests')
        self.spawn(['bash', 'run_all.sh'])
        os.chdir(pwd)

def pysuite():
    return unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests/python_tests')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        name='so',
        version='0.1',
        ext_modules=exts,
        test_suite='setup.pysuite',
        cmdclass={'test': test}
    )
```

I extended the original `test` command, running some extra stuff after the python unit tests finish (notice calling of an external command via `self.spawn`). All that is left is replacing the default `test` command with the custom one via passing `cmdclass` in the setup function.

Now you have everything collected in the setup script and `python setup.py test` will do all the dirty job.

> But, not being sudo on the gitlab's server, I get the following error

I don't have any experience with Gitlab CI, but I can't imagine there is no possibility to install packages on the build server. Maybe this question will be helpful: [How to use sudo in build script for gitlab ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383887/how-to-use-sudo-in-build-script-for-gitlab-ci)

If there really is no other option, you can [bootstrap a local copy of `setuptools` with `ez_setup.py`](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#bootstrapping-setuptools). Note, however, that although this method still works, [it was deprecated recently](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581).

Also, if you happen to use a recent version of Python (3.4 and newer), then you should have `pip` bundled with Python distribution, so it should be possible to install `setuptools` without root permissions with

```
$ python -m pip install --user setuptools
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! However, my tests are not located in the same directory than the wrapper and the command `python setup.py test` doesn't find any, which could be solved quite easily I guess. The problem is that this solution still assumes the ability to load `setuptools`, which isn't the case with my problem...
Thanks about the two other links, I'll check them out and add an answer if I find one that solves my issue.

Comment: You can adjust the test discovery in the setup script, there is an example of doing this in the answer. If you mean the C tests, I have updated the answer with descending into the test directory (via `os.chdir`).

Comment: As for the permission issue, can you share more details? Is this a system where you are a non-root user without any chance of getting `sudo` permissions from your admin? Can you check whether `sudo apt install` works by chance? Also, what Python version is preinstalled/targeted (`python -V`)? Do you have `pip` available for the targeted Python distribution (`pip -V`)? There are still some other options available, like building a local installation of Python from source and installing any packages you need locally, or running a fresh docker container where you will have root access.

Comment: Thanks, yes adjusting the tests discovery seems like the natural option, but there's still the issue that this requires `setuptools`. Yeah I did try with `sudo apt install` and get the same error. Unfortunately no, I cannot have sudo access. I don't know what's the version running on the server, it must be Python 3.5.4, but I'll double check!  I do have `pip`, yes.

Comment: Yes, regarding docker I have never used it but I looked it up and this looks like a good solution to my problem. Have you ever runned tests with docker on gitlab ?

Comment: If you have `pip` available and even a recent Python, using docker just to install `setuptools` is an overkill - use `pip install --user setuptools` or `python -m pip install --user setuptools` and you're good to go. Check first whether `pip` and `python` match the targeted versions, replace with specific `pip3.5`/`python3.5`/etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, adding `python -m pip install --user setuptools` did the trick! You can modify your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks a mil

Comment: Nice, glad I could help! I've mentioned the method in the answer, last paragraph.