# Gitlab-ci - Pipeline Fails to run

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I get the following error when i try to run the pipeline

`sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper`

Has this got something to do with gitlab-runner permissions? I have tried giving it full access, but still it fails. Can someone help me out?

I am following the guide mentioned on gitlab at
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html

**Gitlab Runner**
Version:      13.4.1
Git revision: e95f89a0
Git branch:   13-4-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2020-09-25T20:03:43+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

**Ubuntu**
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: It's good to share what's happening in the pipeline. From the question it's not clear what commands are executed, so it's hard to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seemed to have found a workaround.

as answered by ***@maksim.danilin*** on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2126

- Remove all files from `.*` files from /home/gitlab-runner
- `rm *` should do the trick if you are inside gitlab-runner folder

Futhermore follow the solution by ***@Reactgular*** ([How to use sudo in build script for gitlab ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383887/how-to-use-sudo-in-build-script-for-gitlab-ci?answertab=active#tab-top))

- Grant sudo permissions to the `gitlab-runner` user

  - `$ sudo usermod -a -G sudo gitlab-runner`
- Remove the password restriction for sudo for the gitlab-runner user

  - `$ sudo visudo`
- Add the following to the bottom of the file

  - gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional information if the error is showing as "command not found " . Ensure you have /usr/local/bin/ in $PATH for root or you might get a command not found error. Alternately, you can install gitlab-runner in a different location, like /usr/bin/.

just check

echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

I have documented gitlab runner setup. Feel free to refer!
https://github.com/edureka2021/gitlab.git

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error recently setting up a gitlab CI runner. In my case the sudo error was masking a different error: the command was not found. Just as a sanity-check make sure you can run the command from a shell as the CI user to ensure you're not seeing a false positive from sudo.