# How to bypass gitlab-runner asking for password for sudo commands or What is the default password for gitlab-runners

Tags: shell, gitlab, sudo, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I am new to gitlab runners and trying to automate my project so that whenever a new tag is released, it should build a new deb package. PS: I am using mac and
following [this](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/10/12/automated-debian-package-build-with-gitlab-ci/) official link by gitlab to get my task done

My first gitlab-ci.yml file was(which is just given there on the official link of gitlab I provided above):

```
# Is performed before the scripts in the stages step
before_script:  
  - source /etc/profile

# Defines stages which are to be executed
stages:  
  - build

# Stage "build"
run-build:  
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get install -y libncurses5-dev libglib2.0-dev libgeoip-dev libtokyocabinet-dev zlib1g-dev libncursesw5-dev libbz2-dev
    - autoreconf -fvi
    - cp COPYING debian/copyright
    - dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
    - mkdir build
    - mv ../goaccess*.deb build/

  # This stage is only executed for new tags
  only:
    - tags

  # The files which are to be made available in GitLab
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/*
```

The problem I initially getting with the above gitlab-ci.yml file was:

**Output 1:**

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/GJ7z2Aym/0/edge_release_management/.git/
Checking out 3d71402b as tag1-test...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ source /etc/profile
$ apt-get install -y libncurses5-dev libglib2.0-dev libgeoip-dev libtokyocabinet-dev zlib1g-dev libncursesw5-dev libbz2-dev
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

which says `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied) E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?`

So to resolve the above issue, I thought to change the `brefore_script` part with this

```
# Is performed before the scripts in the stages step
before_script:  
  - source /etc/profile
  - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
  - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_PASSWORD"
#  - sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
#  - sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
  - sudo su
```

Where I am trying to remove `/var/cache/apt/archives/lock` and  `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`, as this is what I found on Google. When it didn't work, I tried `sudo su`. But with the above change, I started to get this issue.

**Output 2:**

```
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/GJ7z2Aym/0/edge_release_management/.git/
Checking out 7fbaaf4f as testing4...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ source /etc/profile
$ sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

It says `sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper sudo: a password is required`

So, to resolve this, I used `sudo -S su < $password_secret` as shown:

```
# Is performed before the scripts in the stages step
before_script:  
  - source /etc/profile
  - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
  - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_PASSWORD"
#  - sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
#  - sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
#  - sudo su
  - sudo -S su < $password_secret
```

Please note: I have saved `$password_secret` in Gitlab variables and it's value is `$password.secret` as someone on google said this can be it's value. I am not sure how true it is.

And now it is giving me this error:
**Output 3:**

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/GJ7z2Aym/0/edge_release_management/.git/
Checking out 0b8ab538 as 26...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:02
$ source /etc/profile
$ echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
Hello, user!
$ echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_PASSWORD"
Hello, 
$ sudo -S su < $password_secret
[sudo] password for gitlab-runner: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for gitlab-runner: 
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

**Please note:** I have also used the way which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383887/how-to-use-sudo-in-build-script-for-gitlab-ci)

But, I found that `usermod` is not there for macOS. So I tried using another way which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70369278/how-to-add-the-current-user-to-the-docker-group-on-macos) using `dscl`. But it still showing me the **Output 3** only

Now I am fed up and unable to think of any other possible ways to fix this. I think I have tried almost everything released to this issue(which might not be true at all, as there must be some solution for this, I believe). Can anyone please help me with this?

**Summary:** Basically my main problem is shown in the first output which says `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied) E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?`. Rest everything I am doing is to resolve it only.