# I asked this question but didn't get any answer for this. Can anyone answer this question?

Tags: shell, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I asked this question but didn't get any answer for this. Can anyone please answer this question?

[How to bypass gitlab-runner asking for password for sudo commands or What is the default password for gitlab-runners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74687461/how-to-bypass-gitlab-runner-asking-for-password-for-sudo-commands-or-what-is-the)

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Do you find any answers attached to the question link you provided? Btw that's my question only. As nobody has provided the answer for that that's why I asked the question again.

Comment: You only asked the other question 19 hours ago. This isn’t a coding service. We’re volunteers. Maybe check out the guide to [ask] and see if you can simplify/streamline your question to make it more likely you’ll get help. Or participate in other ways to [earn some more reputation](/help/whats-reputation) so you can post a [bounty](/help/bounty). But please don’t post a new question linking to your old one.